# MongoDB replace all matching documents

Tags: mongodb

If I have a collection like this:

```
[
   {
     "name":"name1,
     "type":"type1"
   },
   {"name":"name2",
     "type":"type1"
   }
   {
     "name":"name3",
     "type":"type3"
   }
]
```

And I want to replace all of type1 with a list of entries in one atomic operation

```
[{
   "name":"name5"
   "type":"type1"
}]
```

End result would be

```
[
   {
     "name":"name5",
     "type":"type1"
   }
   {
     "name":"name3",
     "type":"type3"
   }
]
```

How can I achieve this? Putting them in a common list complicates things, but maybe its the only way?

Comment: Multiple documents can be updated / replaced in an atomic operation only within a Transaction.